# How to proceed with StrongLifts after illness

Tags: stronglifts, illness

I've been doing StrongLifts for about a month now, but managed to catch the flu this week. Been horizontal for roughly a week.

How should I proceed?

- Start from scratch?
- Move on to the next exercise as if it was just a longer rest period?
- Repeat the last two exercises (A and B) and then continue as normal?
- Deload some amount?
- Other ways?

Of course interested in my particular case, but more generalized answers would be nice too. Sure I'll get sick again while doing StrongLifts as I plan to try at it for a while :)

---

**Weight:** ~85kg **Height:** 179cm **Lifted last:** S 37.5kg, BP 27.5kg, BBR 37.5kg, OHP 27.5kg, DL 55kg

Comment: I'll try to pull the quote from SS (same principles, really) later, but in essence, repeat your last workout. If you feel weak during the warmup, feel free to deload a little (eg. 10%) - this will also allow you to focus on form.

Comment: Knowing your weight, height, and how much you're lifting would help.

Comment: @VPeric That would be interesting. Please add as answer when you find it :)

Comment: Not being able to follow a training program is part of life :) See this question for a general approach http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/7172/3778

Answer (score 2):

First let's start off with the answer for this specific scenario:

Being only 1 month into the program, it is unlikely that you are at a significant enough weight that would warrant a deload. Additionally, with only 1 week of missed workouts, it is unlikely you have had a significant enough deterioration in strength to warrant a deload. Given this, *unless your body tells you otherwise,* you should repeat your previous session and then proceed as normal. Should you have difficulties repeating the previous workout, then deload 10% and work your way back up.

As far as the more generalized answer, that is rather tricky as there are a lot of different stages and scenarios where this answer will change. Generally speaking, when you are working in the heavier weights, safety and form should always come before progress. You cannot and should not attempt to progress to higher weights if it means sacrificing form and/or safety. This is why deloading is such a crucial tool. If you miss a week or two to sickness in the later stages when you are operating at heavy weights, then deloading should no longer be a question, it should be a reality. Go down by 10-20% and start over again, focusing on form and rebuilding muscle so you can get back to and break through your previous weight.